How to Watch changes in folders in KUBERNETES / go lang
In the Kubernetes environment, we are using configmap as a mount to a specific folder.
The configmap is often modified and updated to kubectl application -f [configmap-name]
I want to use fsnotify to monitor the mounted folder, but the watcher does not detect it
Is there anything I don't know about Kubernetes' configmap mount?
type watcherer struct {
    fswatcher *fsnotify.Watcher
    notify    eventer
    watches   map[string]struct{}
    stop      chan struct{}
    logger    log.Logger
}

func (w *watcherer) add(path string) error {
    return w.fswatcher.Add(path)
}

func (w *watcherer) run() {
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-w.stop:
                return
            case evt := <-w.fswatcher.Events:
                w.logger.Infoln("WATCHR EVT COME |", "evt:", evt, "evt.name:", evt.Name, "evt.op:", evt.Op)
                if evt.Op&fsnotify.Remove == fsnotify.Remove {
                    if err := w.remove(evt.Name); err != nil {
                        w.logger.Errorf("%v, %v", evt, err)
                    }
                    if err := w.add(evt.Name); err != nil {
                        w.logger.Errorf("%v, %v", evt, err)
                    }
                    if err := w.notify.syncEvent(event{evt}); err != nil {
                        w.logger.Errorf("%v, %v", evt, err)
                    }
                }
                if evt.Op&fsnotify.Write == fsnotify.Write {
                    w.logger.Infoln("GET CHANGE!!!")
                    if err := w.notify.syncEvent(event{evt}); err != nil {
                        w.logger.Errorf("%v, %v", evt, err)
                    }
                }
            case err := <-w.fswatcher.Errors:
                w.logger.Error(err)
            }
        }
    }()
}

I'll skip the init process, I'll create the following structure, specify the mount folder through add, and then wait for the event through run, but
" w.logger.Infoln("WATCHR EVT COME |", "evt:", evt, "evt.name:", evt.Name, "evt.op:", evt.Op)" I can't find this part in the log
this is configmap.
My ultimate goal is to monitor the agent.yaml file in configmap
but file on mount folder is link.
I'm monitoring the folder because I don't think I can monitor the link. Please advise
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: agent-config
data:
  agent.yaml: |     


.
.
.


drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 78 Oct 24 19:34 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 47 Oct 24 19:32 ../
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 24 Oct 24 19:34 ..2024_10_24_10_34_25.3349338504/
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 32 Oct 24 19:34 ..data -> ..2024_10_24_10_34_25.3349338504/
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Oct 24 19:32 agent.yaml -> ..data/agent.yaml


How to get notification inside an application in kubernetes when configmaps get updated seems very similar to this; does its answer help you?  That notes that you need to watch the symlinks to see the data change, and also that if you're using the github.com/spf13/viper configuration library that it's already aware of this.

Thank you so much! , but i want to know why can't detect to symlinks in fsnotify ㅜ.ㅜ

You need to watch for the "..data" directory. You don't need these extra libraries nor having to listen for configmap changes. It acts as a symlink to the latest version of the ConfigMap.

Thank you Ryan, but after checking the idone [..data] also changes when I change the configuration map

I'm curious about what do you mean by idone. Does checking for the "..data" directory solve the issue on your end? Do you need other help?

sorry Forget it, please,
./ The entire path has been added, but event detection is still not detected

Can you update the question with the latest code? I will try to troubleshoot and reproduce the issue. I am trying to come up with a simple solution that does not depend on using another library.
